# How to query Airtable relational data using Gridsome and Graphql?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, airtable, gridsome

I am using the Airtable templates and Gridsome to query the Furniture in the Product catalogue templates. In AirTable the furniture data table has a "designers" property that has a value of the id of the designer who created the piece of furniture. The idea is that with that ID value I create another query and get all the data for the specific designer. the designers have their own table so my question is. how do I create a relational query getting the path to the ID and the data of the "designers"?

my gridsome.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteName: 'Furniture Store',
  plugins: [
    {
      use: '@gridsome/source-airtable',
      options: {
        apiKey: 'keyhMlUJl9q3uzk0b', // required
        baseId: 'appkEp5El5UHrgnks', // required
        tableName: 'Furniture', // required
        typeName: 'Product', // required
      }
    },

    {
      use: '@gridsome/source-airtable',
      options: {
        apiKey: 'keyhMlUJl9q3uzk0b', // required
        baseId: 'appkEp5El5UHrgnks', // required
        tableName: 'Designers', // required
        typeName: 'Designers', // required
      }
    },
  ],
  templates: {
    Designers: '/designer/:id' // optional
  }
}
```

Index.vue

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    <h1>Furniture store</h1>
    <ProductCard
      v-for="product in $page.allProduct.edges"
      :key="product.node.id"
      :product="product"
      />
  </Layout>
</template>


<page-query>
query {
  allProduct {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        designer
        description
        type
        inStock
        images {
          thumbnails {
            large {
              url
              width
              height
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



</page-query>


<script>
import ProductCard from '~/components/ProductCard';

export default {
  components: {
    ProductCard
  }
}
</script>
```

components/ProductCard.vue

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-card
        class="mx-auto my-12"
        max-width="374"
    >
            <v-img
            height="250"
            :src="product.node.images[0].thumbnails.large.url"
            ></v-img>

            <v-card-title>{{ product.node.name }}</v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>
        <v-row
            align="center"
            class="mx-0"
        >
            <v-rating
            :value="4.5"
            color="amber"
            dense
            half-increments
            readonly
            size="14"
            ></v-rating>

            <div class="grey--text ml-4">4.5 (413)</div>
        </v-row>

        <div class="my-4 subtitle-1 black--text">
            {{ product.node.description }}
        </div>

          <g-link to="/">Link to Designer</g-link>
        </v-card-text>

        <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>

        <v-card-title>Tonight's availability</v-card-title>
    </v-card>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ProductCard',
    props: {
        product: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },

}
</script>
```

templates/Designer.vue

```
 <template>
   <h1>{{ $page.designers.name }}</h1>
 </template>

 <page-query>
 query Designer($id: ID!) {
  designers(id: $id) {
    name
    id
    bio
  }
}
 </page-query>
```

any helps is much appreciated!!

Comment: Recently there was an update to the Gridsome Airtable Plugin that allows a `links` option to be specified in `gridsome.config` that might be useful here: https://gridsome.org/plugins/@gridsome/source-airtable

Comment: thanks  i will look into it